# How to click Facebook Like button using Webdriver

Tags: facebook-like, webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to click Facebook Like button using Webdriver. You can see an example Like button [at this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

After switching to iframe I've tried:

```
page.execute_script("document.querySelector('.pluginConnectButton > div:first-child button').click()")
```

This script works in Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools after switching to iframe.

But it doesn't work in FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver (script passes but button isn't changed to clicked one)

How can I click this button using Webdriver?

Comment: Can you show the working example?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain There's working Like button at [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I need to click button at another page but buttons are the same.

Comment: I was able to get this to work in watir-webdriver, but I had to trigger the mouseover event for the button before clicking it. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to replicate the same in  Capybara or Selenium-Webdriver. Facebook might also be checking for the use of webdriver as you can see in the iframe that it will see some webddriver attribute equal to true.

Answer (score 4):

While this worked for me it seems brittle. I had to use some javascript to get the id of the iframe since FB changes the id on each page load. Luckily they're not changing the class of the iframe.

```
id = page.evaluate_script("$('.fb_ltr').attr('id');")
within_frame(id) do
  page.first(:css, '.pluginButton').click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This to work for you.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Like[\\s\\S]*$")== true) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='u_0_1']/div/div/div/button")).click();
}
else{
System.out.println("Unable to click Like button on page");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using page-object gem. here is my way to click Like fb button:

```
 in_frame(:class =>"fb_ltr") do |frame|
    button(:fb_btn, :css => "#facebook div.pluginButton.pluginButtonSmall.pluginButtonInline.pluginConnectButtonDisconnected button" , :frame => frame)
  end
```

...

```
fb_btn_element.when_present.click
```